# Lisp Koans Scoring Project: Refactor

Tags: common-lisp

I am going through [Lisp Koans](https://github.com/google/lisp-koans), it's a lot of fun! But I stuck at Scoring Projects (I had a bad solution). In this project we were asked to implement a simple game called `*Greed*`. The problem description is here:

```
; *Greed* is a dice game where you roll up to five dice to accumulate
; points.  The following "score" function will be used to calculate the
; score of a single roll of the dice.
;
; A greed roll is scored as follows:
; * A set of three ones is 1000 points
; * A set of three numbers (other than ones) is worth 100 times the
;   number. (e.g. three fives is 500 points).
; * A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points.
; * A five (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 50 points.
; * Everything else is worth 0 points.
;
; Examples:
;
; (score '(1 1 1 5 1)) => 1150 points
; (score '(2 3 4 6 2)) => 0 points
; (score '(3 4 5 3 3)) => 350 points
; (score '(1 5 1 2 4)) => 250 points
;
; More scoring examples are given in the tests below:
;
; Your goal is to write the score method.
```

My Solution is following:

## WARNING! IF YOU HAVEN'T PLAY WITH THIS ONE. DO NOT SEE THIS!

I use an `occurs` function to calculate occurrences of number and represent in assoc-list. And a `formula-wrapper` function to provide correct arguments to `formula` function. The `formula` function to calculate scores. My solution is very ugly! Any advices are welcome! Thank you in advance.

```
(defun occurs (lst)
  (let ((acc nil))
    (dolist (obj lst)
      (let ((p (assoc obj acc)))
        (if p
            (incf (cdr p))
            (push (cons obj 1) acc))))
    (sort acc  #'> :key #'cdr)))

(defun formula-wrapper (lst)
  (formula (car lst) (cdr lst)))

(defun formula (number times)
  (cond ((= times 0) 0)
        ((= times 1)
         (case number
           (1 100)
           (5 50)
           (otherwise 0)))
        ((= times 2)
         (case number
           (1 200)
           (5 100)
           (otherwise 0)))
        ((= times 3)
         (case number
           (1 1000)
           (otherwise (* 100 number))))
        ((= times 4)
         (case number
           (1 1100)
           (5 550)
           (otherwise 0)))
        ((= times 5)
         (case number
           (1 1200)
           (5 600)
           (otherwise 0)))
        (times 0)))

(defun score (dice)
  (let ((rolls (occurs dice)))
    (if (null rolls)
        0
        (apply #'+ (mapcar #'formula-wrapper rolls))))))
```

### The tests:

```
(define-test test-score-of-an-empty-list-is-zero
    (assert-equal 0 (score nil)))

(define-test test-score-of-a-single-roll-of-5-is-50
    (assert-equal 50 (score '(5))))


(define-test test-score-of-a-single-roll-of-1-is-100
    (assert-equal 100 (score '(1))))

(define-test test-score-of-multiple-1s-and-5s-is-the-sum-of-individual-scores
    (assert-equal 300 (score '(1 5 5 1))))

(define-test test-score-of-single-2s-3s-4s-and-6s-are-zero
    (assert-equal 0 (score '(2 3 4 6))))


(define-test test-score-of-a-triple-1-is-1000
    (assert-equal 1000  (score '(1 1 1))))

(define-test test-score-of-other-triples-is-100x
    (assert-equal 200  (score '(2 2 2)))
    (assert-equal 300  (score '(3 3 3)))
    (assert-equal 400  (score '(4 4 4)))
    (assert-equal 500  (score '(5 5 5)))
    (assert-equal 600  (score '(6 6 6))))

(define-test test-score-of-mixed-is-sum
    (assert-equal 250  (score '(2 5 2 2 3)))
    (assert-equal 550  (score '(5 5 5 5))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to write it:

```
(defun find-set (roll)
  "which number from 1 to 6 occurs at least three times in a list of five?"
  (assert (= (length roll) 5))
  (loop for i from 1 to 6
        when (>= (count i roll) 3)
        do (return i)))

(defun score-set (i)
  "compute the set score for number i" 
  (case i
    (1 1000)
    (otherwise (* i 100))))

(defun score (roll &aux (s (find-set roll)) (score 0))
  (when s
    (setf score (score-set s)
          roll (remove s roll :count 3)))
  (incf score (* (count 1 roll) 100))
  (incf score (* (count 5 roll) 50))
  score)

(defun test ()
  (assert (= (score '(1 1 1 5 1)) 1150))
  (assert (= (score '(2 3 4 6 2)) 0))
  (assert (= (score '(3 4 5 3 3)) 350))
  (assert (= (score '(1 5 1 2 4)) 250))
  t)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun score (dice)
  (let ((freq (make-hash-table)))
    (loop for x in dice do (incf (gethash x freq 0)))
    (loop for x being the hash-key of freq using (hash-value c)
          sum (if (<= 3 c)
                  (case x
                    (1 (+ 1000 (* 100 (- c 3))))
                    (5 (+  500 (*  50 (- c 3))))
                    (t (* x 100)))
                  (case x
                    (1 (* c 100))
                    (5 (* c  50))
                    (t 0))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A tail-recursive version:

```
(defun score (dice)
  (labels ((iter (left ans)
             (if (not left) ans
                 (cond ((and (>= (length left) 3)
                             (= (car left) (cadr left) (caddr left)))
                        (cond ((= (car left) 1)
                               (iter (cdddr left) (+ ans 1000)))
                              ((= (car left) 5)
                               (iter (cdddr left) (+ ans 500)))
                              (t (iter (cdddr left) (+ ans (* (car left) 100))))))
                       ((= (car left) 1) (iter (cdr left) (+ ans 100)))
                       ((= (car left) 5) (iter (cdr left) (+ ans 50)))
                       (t (iter (cdr left) ans))))))
    (iter (sort dice #'<) 0)))
```